# TransitionTo child path where parent has dynamic segment

Tags: javascript, ember.js, url-routing

As the title suggests I'm trying to `transitionTo` a child path from a action. The problem is that Ember says that it can't find any paths with that name. Looking at the Ember docs I've no idea what I'm doing wrong here. I'm hoping someone here might have the expertise to help me out.

Ember Error:

```
Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: The route post.comments was not found
```

Application route definition:

```
this.resource('post', { path: 'post/:post_id' }, function () {
    this.resource('comments');
});
```

The `transitionTo` in the action:

```
route.transitionTo('post.comments', post_id);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Route `post.comments` doesn't exist because you define `comments` as `resource` instead of `route`. I guess this should work:

```
this.resource('post', { path: 'post/:post_id' }, function () {
    this.route('comments');
});

route.transitionTo('post.comments', post_id);
```

However if you really need to declare `comments` as resource, use:

```
route.transitionTo('comments', post_id);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, that's a typo indeed. This is because it's called a little different in the code but it's practically the same as with posts and comments. I've edited out that little mistake. Thank you for showing me!

Comment: No problem. Remember that when you use `router.resource()` "parent route" is removed from name of the route. So `post.comments` becomes `comments`.